# GUI tool for API testing with possibility to choose HTTP protocol version

Tags: tools, api-testing, api, http, test-tools

I'm looking for a GUI tool for API testing that allows for changing a HTTP protocol version.

There're many tools for API testing, but all I've found don't offer a choice of selecting what HTTP protocol version will be used in requests. Examples are Postman that [doesn't support http2 at all](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2701), nor it allows for [changing HTTP version in requests](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6242).

Insomnia or Firecamp both support http2, but they always send it in  TLS handshake, therefore it's not possible to omit this from the TLS handshake and force the tools to use e.g. HTTP/1.1

[image]

As of now, I know only about curl that supports the [selection of HTTP version](https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-versions), e.g.:

```
curl -v --http1.1 -D - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts -o /dev/null
```

This will instruct curl to not send http2 option in TLS handshake:

[image]

So, what I'm looking for is a GUI tool similar to Postman that offers what curl does regarding the choice of HTTP protocol version. **What are such tools?**

Comment: Do you really need GUI? Why?

Comment: @dzieciou I'm mostly curious about what's available. It seems to me I'd be able to find a non-GUI tool with such capabilities with no problem, but the situation with Postman and others is different. However, if you know about something non-GUI, I'd be glad if you shared it as well.

Comment: @pavelsaman, We're working on it at the POC level. If all goes well then you'll have this support soon in Firecamp.

Answer (score 1):

In the version of Insomnia I am using (2021.3.0) you can change the HTTP version in the settings. The options are Default, HTTP 1.0, HTTP 1.1, HTTP/2

Answer (score 1):

I created a GUI tool for testing HTTP requests, with support for HTTP/2 and HTTP/3. It has full compatibility with existing Postman collections and environments.

https://github.com/alexandrehtrb/Pororoca